# BDI walking does not work in my PC

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi.

I tried BDI walking script, but it did not work.
Atlas failed to walk in simulation world.
Is it 'my' problem?
I want to know whether another user can success atlas BDI walking or not.

I did following process for testing.
drcsim version is 2.3.

1)start simulation

```
 $ roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

2)run BDI walking scripts

```
 $ cd /usr/share/drcsim-2.3/ros/atlas_utils/scripts
 $ ./5steps.py
```

Then, atlas falls down.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2285/bdi-walking-does-not-work-in-my-pc./) by [Yuto Nakanish](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/304/yuto-nakanish/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [klowrey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/113/klowrey/) on 2013-04-09**:
If you reset the world/model pose, and then run 5steps.py again, it works (for me at least). Not that this is all that helpful, but if you just needed to collect some data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's a known (and [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/183/bdi-expects-body1force-and-body1torque/diff)) problem for the current drcsim_2.3 packages  http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2274/atlas-failing-in-boston-dynamics-controller-demo/.

**Immediate solution:**
It was fixed in the drcsim 2.3 branch of drcsim repository. To have it working compile drcsim from source using the drcsim_2.3 branch.

**Short term solution:**
A short release cycle for this 2.3.1 version is planned which will ship this fix and can be installed using ubuntu packages.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/305/kei-okada/) on 2013-04-10**:
I uses 2.3.1 but the robot falls ii  drcsim         2.3.1-1~precis Darpa Robotics Challengue (DRC) simulator